# Casting a Vec<u8> to a &[u16]

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<u8>` of bytes read from a file - the bytes are a text format (probably UTF-16 or some other silly 2 byte format) and I want to turn it into UTF-8.

```
let title = Vec::from_iter(bytes.take(title_length));
// Some Vec<u8> to &[u16] magic
let title = String::from_utf16_lossy(title);
```

Currently I'm using this rather dirty code:

```
let title: &[u16] = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(title_data.as_ptr(), title_data.len()) };
```

While this should work I'm getting errors probably due to the `take()` call:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `*const u16`,
    found `*const core::result::Result<u8, std::io::error::Error>`
(expected u16,
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
```

Should I `map` the `take` iterator or something?

Comment: That would've been a very good question, didn't it look incomplete. ;)

Comment: That's weird. It was giving me issues while saving it too. Hangon a second :/

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem. One line of your code references `title_data`, but that's never defined anywhere. Ideally, provide code that reproduces the error on [the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)

Answer (score 8):

## With Safe Code

Just in case you need to do it safely,

```rust
let title = Vec::from_iter(bytes.take(title_length));
let title: Vec<u16> = title
    .chunks_exact(2)
    .into_iter()
    .map(|a| u16::from_ne_bytes([a[0], a[1]]))
    .collect();
let title = title.as_slice();
let title = String::from_utf16_lossy(title);
```

Note that this will allocate memory, and do an extra copy (which the unsafe alternatives don't do).

Answer (score 1):

In the end I mapped unwrap over the iterator, though I'm still confused as to why an iterator needs to consist of results.

```
let title_data = Vec::from_iter(bytes.take(title_length).map(|x| x.unwrap()));
let title: &[u16] = unsafe {
    std::slice::from_raw_parts(title_data.as_ptr() as *const u16, title_data.len() / 2)
};
let title = String::from_utf16_lossy(title);
```

Comment: because it's an IO iterator and IO operations can fail. Would you prefer your application to quit with a panic just because some file could no longer be read?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors. First, you need to `.unwrap()` your `Result` (of `from_raw_parts(..)`, I presume), second the length is too large, because a `u16` takes twice the space of a `u8`, so you need to divide by 2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't unwrap the result - `from_raw_parts` is giving me a slice *containing* results: `error: no method named 'unwrap' found for type '&[core::result::Result<u8, std::io::error::Error>]' in the current scope`

Comment: See, that's why you should have written a complete example. I can only guess that `bytes` returns `Option<Result<u8, Error>>`s.

Comment: It doesn't. [It returns `std::iter::Take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Bytes.html#method.take)